# connected component analysis error

Tags: matlab, image-processing, connected-components

I'm trying to do connected component analysis.but I'm getting error. I need the vertebral body ;but I'm getting some other objects.
Image is:

[image: image1]

Result is:

[image: result]

```
    im= imread('im.bmp');
    figure,imshow(im);
    K1=imadjust(im);
    figure, imshow(K1), title('After Adjustment Image')
    threshold = graythresh(K1);
    originalImage = im2bw(K1, threshold);

    originalImage = bwareaopen(originalImage,100);
    se = strel('disk', 2); %# structuring element
    closeBW = imclose(originalImage,se);

    figure,imshow(closeBW);

    CC = bwconncomp(closeBW);
    L = labelmatrix(CC);
    L2 = bwlabel(K1);
    figure, imshow(label2rgb(L));
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include some images of what you want and what you got instead?

Comment: Would you be able to link to it, then?

Comment: added image.please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segmentation isn't my area, so I'm not sure what the best approach is. Here are a couple heuristic ideas I came up with:

1. Discard regions that are too big or too small.

It looks like you can expect a certain size from the vertebra.

```
regionIdxs = unique(L(:));
regionSizes = accumarray(L(:)+1,1);
```

If we look at `regionSizes`, we see the region sizes in pixels:

```
  213360
     919
     887
     810
     601
     695
   14551
     684
    1515
     414
     749
     128
     173
   26658
```

The regions you want (rows 2-6) are on the range 500-1000. We can probably safely discard regions that are <200 or >2000 in size.

```
goodRegionIdx = (regionSizes>200) & (regionSizes<2000);
regionIdxs = regionIdxs(goodRegionIdx);
regionSizes = regionSizes(goodRegionIdx);
```

2. Look at the [image moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) of the desired regions.

The eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of a distribution characterize its size in its widest direction and its size perpendicular to that direction. We are looking for fat disk-shapes, so we can expect a big eigenvalue and a medium-sized eigenvalue.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(L,2),1:size(L,1));
for i = 1:length(regionIdxs)
    idx = regionIdxs(i);
    region = L==idx;
    totalmass = sum(region(:));

    Ex(i)  = sum( X(1,:).*sum(region,1) )  / totalmass;
    Ey(i)  = sum( Y(:,1).*sum(region,2))   / totalmass;
    Exy(i) = sum(sum( X.*Y.*region ))      / totalmass;
    Exx(i) = sum(sum( X.*X.*region ))      / totalmass;
    Eyy(i) = sum(sum( Y.*Y.*region ))      / totalmass;

    Varx(i)  = Exx(i) - Ex(i)^2;
    Vary(i)  = Eyy(i) - Ey(i)^2;
    Varxy(i) = Exy(i) - Ex(i)*Ey(i);

    Cov = [Varx(i) Varxy(i); Varxy(i) Vary(i)];

    eig(i,:) = eigs(Cov);
end
```

If we look at the eigenvalues `eig`:

```
  177.6943   30.8029
  142.4484   35.9089
  164.6374   26.2081
  112.6501   22.7570
  138.1674   24.1569
   89.8082   58.8964
  284.2280   96.9304
   83.3226   15.9994
  113.3122   33.7410
```

We are only interested in rows 1-5, which have eigenvalues on the range 100-200 for the largest and below 50 the the second. If we discard these, get the following regions:

```
goodRegionIdx = (eig(:,1)>100) & (eig(:,1)<200) & (eig(:,2)<50);
regionIdxs = regionIdxs(goodRegionIdx);
```

We can plot the regions by using logical OR `|`.

```
finalImage = false(size(L));
for i = 1:length(regionIdxs)
    finalImage = finalImage | (L==regionIdxs(i) );
end
```

[image]

We seem to get one false positive. Looking at the ratio of the eigenvalues `eig(:,1)./eig(:,2)` is one idea but that seem to be a little problematic too.

You could try some sort of outlier detection like [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) to try and eliminate the region you don't want, since true vertebra tend to be spatially aligned along a line or curve.

I'm not sure what else to suggest. You may have to look into more advanced segmentation methods like machine learning if you can't find another way to discriminate the good from the bad. Having a stricter preprocessing method might be one thing to try.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user3217708 I added the plotting code above the final image. What do you mean by "vertebral bodies"?

Comment: @user3217708 I don't know of an easy way to isolate those. I suggest you do a little research or segmentation algortihms for medical imaging and see what you can find.

Comment: @user3217708 `accumarray(L,1)` takes a list of labels `L` and counts the total number of occurrences for each label. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#examples) for more info.

Comment: @user3217708 Try `imagesc(finalImage)` or `imshow(finalImage,[])`.

Comment: @user3217708 Maybe star ta new question which includes relevant code, the things you have tried to solve the problem, and the results you are getting.